# Add a header above existing websites

Tags: html, css, header, proxy

I'm in the process of setting up a proxy site and I'm trying to add a small header to the top of each page (about 40px, just enough for a text box to allow the user to change the website they are browsing through the proxy).  Unfortunately everything I've tried so far places the header on top of the existing page covering the top part of the page.  I'm trying to figure out a way to place the header above the page, moving all the contents of the page down 40px.  Any help is highly appreciated.

Thanks.

P.S.  I figured out that the content that seems to be causing the most issues is content that is absolutely positioned to the top of the page.

Answer (score 0):

```
<br clear="all" />
```

Place that underneath the new div and above all the content you want the site topbar to sit above

Comment: The clear attribute don't exist. It should be: <br style="clear:all" />

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't do it, but I think I figured out which content is causing issues, it's absolute positioned content that's not getting pushed down.  Is there any way to make such content move down?

Answer (score 0):

This should show a header of 40 px in your page:

```
<div style="height:40px;width:100%;display:block">My small header</div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately not all of the content in the proxied page gets pushed down.  The majority of the content does, but things like top menus, etc. (things ties to the top of the page by the website, probably using absolute positioning) simply get covered over by this div.

Answer (score 0):

without seeing the HTML, we're flying blind, but based on your description, I think you've got a site where direct children of the body element are absolutely positioned at the top. The solutions I would pursue involves a wrapping those direct children in a relatively positioned div (or section) and then just insert your new content above that div.

Your structure should go from

```
<body>
   <div>this is absolutely positioned</div>
</body>
```

to

```
<body>
    <div>this is your new header</div>
    <div class="relatively position wrapped">
        <div>this is absolutely positioned</div>
    </div>
</body>
```

This will allow your new content to affect the positioning of the stuff that comes after.

The problem you're looking at is based on the fact that absolutely positioned elements have no place in the document flow, so for best control, you place them in a relatively positioned element that does effect the document flow, and is effected by surrounding elements.

If all of the offending elements are positioned at the top, you could just give each of the a style attribute like style="top: 40px" (better yet, do that in the css).

If you want to wrap the offending elements but don't want to mess with the html, you could use jquery:

```
jQuery(body).innerWrap('<div style="position: relative;"></div>');
jQuery(body).prepend('<div>your new content</div>');
```